# How can I declare a Blazor component<TData,TValue>?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Update - here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a component - ItemTagBox.razor:

```
<DxTagBox Data="@Data"
          TData="IItemFlyweight"
          TValue="IItemFlyweight"
          Values="@Values"
          ValuesExpression="@(() => Values)"
          ValuesChanged="ValuesChanged">

@*  Several nodes for custom display that require TData & TValue be IItemFlyweight *@

</DxTagBox>
```

And ItemTagBox.razor.cs:

```
public partial class ItemTagBox : ExComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<IItemFlyweight>? Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<IItemFlyweight>? Values { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<IEnumerable<IItemFlyweight>> ValuesChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? DefaultThumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

These are using [the DevExpress component DxTagBox<TData,TValue>](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxTagBox-2).

What I would like is that when I call it like this:

```
<ItemTagBox Data="AllUsers"
@bind-Values="@(((EventItemPageModel)context.EditModel).HostsEnumerable)"
            DefaultThumbnail="@SystemBlobs.CertificationThumbnail" />
```

In this case the Data & Values are of type `List<UserFlyweight>`. I would like it to then understand that Data & Value are a List<> of UserFlyweight and not IItemFlyweight.

And that this carries through to inside ItemTagBox.razor so that DxTagBox knows it is getting a List for the Data and Values. So the specific type is known all the way down and back.

And yes `class UserFlyweight : IItemFlyweight`

---

The DxListBox and DxComboBox [are specified in the documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxListBox-2) as:

```
DxListBox<TData, TValue>
```

You can then use them in your razor file as:

```
<DxTagBox Data="@Data"
          TData="IItemFlyweight"
          TValue="string"
          Values="@Values"
```

And in the above, both the `DxTagBox` and the VisualStudio intellisense know that Data is of type `IEnumerable<IItemFlyweight>` and Values is of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

So first off, what's going on here?

Second, I have created a component that has a DxTagBox in it. How do I declare my component so it can be called with a TData and TValue attribute that I can then assign to the DxTagBox?

So I can then do:

```
<MyComponent Data="@Data"
          TData="IItemFlyweight"
          TValue="string"
          Values="@Values"
```

And inside it I can do:

```
<DxTagBox Data="@Data"
          TData="@TData"
          TValue="@TValue"
          Values="@Values"
```

Comment: @BrianParker In my case I have a component that is calling in itself DxTagBox<TData,TValue> and so I need to pass that through. I think. Or is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@typeparam` directive.

Inside your MyComponent.razor you need to declare the `@typeparam`'s.

```
@typeparam TData
@typeparam TValue


@code{
[Parameter] public IEnumerable<TData> Data {get;set;}
[Parameter] public IEnumerable<TValue> Values {get;set;}
}
```

Then you use can use it like so.

```
<MyComponent Data="@Data"
          TData="IItemFlyweight"
          TValue="string"
          Values="@Values"
```

[Demo snippet Link](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QuwxOimUEOXWQrHH)

### For generic type constraints

You can declare the type constraints in the component  `MyComponent.razor` or code behind `MyComponent.razor.cs` or both.

##### To declare it in the component

```
@typeparam TData where TData : IItemFlyweight
@typeparam TValue
```

##### To declare in the code behind.

*Note* If you're using any of the types in the razor markup then you need to declare the `@typeparam` there aswell with or without the constraints.

```
public partial class MyComponent<TData,TValue>
 where TData : IItemFlyweight
{
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TData> Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TValue> Values { get; set; }
}
```

---

#### Compile error when using Type constraints in the component

While I was testing `@typeparam TData where TData : IItemFlyweight` in VS2022 `v.17.7.2`, .NET 7 Blazor-Server,  I ran across this compile error. Seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8572).

```
RZ1017: Unexpected literal following the 'typeparam' directive. Expected 'line break'.
```

Workaround for this is to make slight changes to the `.csproj` e.g. changing the project to .NET 6 then back to .NET 7.

---

##### Just saw the question update, for your specific code

`ItemTagBox.razor`

```
@inherits ExComponentBase
@typeparam TData

<DxTagBox Data="@Data"
          TData="TData"
          TValue="TData"
          Values="@Values"
          ValuesExpression="@(() => Values)"
          ValuesChanged="OnValuesChanged" />
```

`ItemTagBox.razor.cs`

```
public partial class ItemTagBox<TData> : ExComponentBase
    where TData : IItemFlyWieght
{
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TData>? Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TData>? Values { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<TData>> ValuesChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool ReadOnly { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string? DefaultThumbnail { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValuesChanged(IEnumerable<TData> values)
    {
        await ValuesChanged.InvokeAsync(values.ToList());
    }
}
```

`ParentComponent.razor`

```
<ItemTagBox Data="_myData" TData="UserFlyWeight" @bind-Values="_myValues"/>

@code {

    List<UserFlyWeight> _myData = new() { new() { Name = "data1" }, new() { Name = "data2" } };
    List<UserFlyWeight> _myValues = new() { new() { Name = "value1" }, new() { Name = "value2" } };
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and got a ton of compile errors. Do I need to put it in MyComponent.razor.cs too? Does it matter where I put it in MyComponent.razor? And how do I do the equivilent of `@typeparam TData where TData : IItemFlyweight
`? TIA

Comment: I tend to add it to the top of the component before any markup.  However, it seems it doesn't matter where you place it, it gets hoisted. Updated the answer and added the compile error I ran across while testing and what fixed it for me.

Comment: Np! Is it working as expected? Couldn't really test the UI functionality as I created a dummy DxTagBox component.

Comment: Yes it is. What tripped me up was until I got every bit of it set in the razor and razor.cs files it was giving me errors that made me think it was all wrong. But once I got everything entered right - all good.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have DevExpress, so I can't give you a full context example.  My example uses the standard `InputNumber` control.

In general, the type is inferred and the Razor compiler handles it, so you don't need to declare the type explicitly.

However, if you do, here's how you would do it with a custom control that uses  `InputNumber` [which can take various number types].

```cs
@typeparam TNumber

<InputNumber TValue="TNumber" class="form-control" @bind-Value:get="this.Value" @bind-Value:set="this.ValueChanged" />

@code {
    [Parameter] public TNumber? Value { get; set; } 
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TNumber?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<div class="mb-3">
    <MyInput TNumber="decimal" @bind-Value=_value />
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>@_value</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private decimal _value;
}
```

In your code you would declare:

```cs
@typeparam TData where TData : IItemFlyweight
@typeparam TValue where TValue : IItemFlyweight
```

`DxTagBox` would be:

```cs
<DxTagBox Data="@Data"
          TData="TData"
          TValue="TValue"
          Values="@Values"
          ValuesExpression="@(() => Values)"
          ValuesChanged="ValuesChanged">

</DxTagBox>
```

Your parameters would become:

```cs
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TData>? Data { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<TValue>? Values { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<IEnumerable<TValue>> ValuesChanged { get; set; }
```

And:

```cs
<MyComponent Data="@Data"
          TData="MyItemFlyweightClass"
          TValue="MyItemFlyweightClass"
          Values="@Values"
/>
```

Comment: As always, thank you very much.

Comment: NP - @RBee 's initial answer was correct in that you need to use `@typeparam`,  but a little succinct in how to apply it, so I added this answer.  He's since added more detail to explain how to solve the problem.