# Generic Type Parameter in Razor Component

Tags: c#, generics, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to use a Generic Type parameter with a generic in the where clause like that:

```cs
@typeparam TId
@typeparam TEntity where TEntity : class, IAuditableEntity<TId>
```

Note: This does not compile.

The reason for that is because I want to call the following method in my class library:

```cs
Task<DtoCreateModifiedData> GetCreateModifiedDataById<T, TId>(TId id)
    where T : class, IAuditableEntity<TId>;
```

How can I call the method from a Razor component?

Comment: Declare the type constraints in the code behind, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981136/11779494

Comment: What error does the compiler show?

Comment: `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) RZ1017 Unexpected literal following the 'typeparam' directive. Expected 'line break'.` and

`Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) RZ9980 Unclosed tag 'TId' with no matching end tag.`

Comment: Well it looks like this was just an error in Visual Studio (Clean Solution did not help). I deleted the repo locally and repelled it, now it is working without any changes.

Comment: It's a known [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8572) it's likely to occur everytime you reopen VS, and the workaround is to make slight changes to the csproj file, for example chaning the .net version's. Which is why I was recommending using code behind for generic components with type constaraints.

Comment: As @RBee says, it's a known issue.  It intrigued me for a while: in my own projects it didn't happen, but in projects I made to answer questions it did.  I finally figured it out.  All the UI component code in my projects is in Razor libraries, not part of the WASM or Server deployment project.  It only happens when you try to use Generics in web projects.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the classes and interfaces:

```cs
public class Test
{
    public Task<DtoCreateModifiedData> GetCreateModifiedDataByIdAsync<T, TId>(TId? id)
        where T : class, IAuditableEntity<TId>
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new DtoCreateModifiedData());
    }
}

public interface IAuditableEntity<TId> { }

public class DtoCreateModifiedData { }
```

Service registration:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<Test>();
```

And `MyTypeComponent`.

```cs
@typeparam TId
@typeparam TEntity where TEntity : class, IAuditableEntity<TId>
@inject Test TestService

@code {
    [Parameter] public TId? Value { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var data = await this.TestService.GetCreateModifiedDataByIdAsync<TEntity, TId>(Value);
    }
}
```

Note: I've renamed `GetCreateModifiedDataById` to `GetCreateModifiedDataByIdAsync` as that's the standard convention for async methods.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was just an issue with any Visual Studio Cache. I repulled the project and everything is fine now.